# Tensorflow neural network predicts different answers for the same data after creating a server

Tags: python, tensorflow, server, neural-network

I have trained a neural network using TensorFlow 1.8.0 and eager execution.
After training I saved it and there were no problems with loading and predicting.
Then I made a python server (using flask) which loads the trained model to receive POST requests with data in format json, which is later standardized and proceeded to the model.
But now every time I restart the server the neural network gives different answers with different probabilities.
I have checked that:

- the data received by the server a really the same.
- when manually restoring the network without a server and manually giving the data to it - all the answers are the same with the same probabilities.

This is how the code looks like:

```
imports
tf.enable_eager_execution()

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
...
])
optimizer
root = tfe.Checkpoint(optimizer=optimizer, model=model, optimizer_step=tf.train.get_or_create_global_step())    
root.restore(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_directory))

@app.route('/calc', methods=['POST'])
def predict_data():
    read and parse json
    class_ids = ["false", "true"]
    predict_data = tf.convert_to_tensor([data_to_predict])
    predictions = model(predict_data)
    for i, logits in enumerate(predictions):
        class_idx = tf.argmax(logits).numpy()
        p = tf.nn.softmax(logits)[class_idx]
        name = class_ids[class_idx]
        return("{\"Result\":"+ name+",\"Probability\":"+str(float(p))+"}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug, port)
```

Seems like some weights are randomly initialized somehow but the problem is that when I'm not using a server, everythig acts as it has to.

Comment: Seeding is needed for random function. Still, variations might come because of parallelism I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was not in the model itself or creating a server.
I used a config file to read the checkpoint directory. I've written there:

```
 checkpointDir = 'path/to/the/checkpoint'
```

but those quotes were unnecessary and the script couldn't read the path, so the model didn't restore and all the variables remained random.

The right way was just:

```
checkpointDir = path/to/the/checkpoint
```

I don't fully understand, why did I need the quotes when I just wrote the full path in the code but didn't need them when writing the config file but that's not the point right now.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you need to set a seed, so in Tensorflow you can try with:

```
tf.set_random_seed(1234)
```

Comment: okay, it stopped predicting randomly but now it predicts different answers than it predicted when I trained it. As far as I understand I need just to set the correct number for a random seed but I don't get what should it be. Could you explain it to me?

Comment: When you are training, the model is calculating the weight and other parameters of the neural network. So during the training you can add the parameter "seed" in each layer like this example: `layer_1 = tf.nn.dropout(layer_1, (1.0 - dropout[0]), seed = tf.set_random_seed(1234))`